# why wouldn't either of document.location or window.location work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the event handler I set up on a button:

```
$('.tabsTD').on('click', 'a.finalSave', (function () {
    var returnStatus= finalSave(this, location);

    if (returnStatus) {
        if ($(this).text() == "Save and Continue") {
            sessionStorage.carePlanReload = "true";
            sessionStorage.activeTab = $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            document.location.reload(false);
        }
        else if ($(this).text() == "Save and Close") {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            document.location = "MemberHome.aspx";
            //setTimeout(function () { document.location = "MemberHome.aspx"; }, 500);
            //return false;
            //$('#aRedirectToHome')[0].click();
            return false;
        }
    } /*END if*/
}));
```

In the `else if` condition, I need to redirect to "memberhome.aspx", but nothing seems to work. I also tried adding an anchor tag, like:

```
<a href="MemberHome.aspx" id="aRedirectToHome" style="display:none;">RedirectToHome</a>
```

and then invoke a click on the anchor from `else if`, but it proved to be a failed attempt.

Please help.

Comment: Could you try it? document.location.href = "window.location.protocol+window.location.host+MemberHome.aspx";

Comment: @LuongDinh please see my comment on the first answer and you have misquoted the statement in the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either pass a new value to the href property as in:

`window.location.href = "MemberHome.aspx";`

or, using assign method as in:

`window.location.assign("MemberHome.aspx");`

Comment: thanks for the response but i tried both ways earlier   and didn't worked,page stays as is ,no redirection

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the window.event.returnValue expression you're using. Please note that this is non-standard and deprecated feature. You might want to comment the line out and see if it works.